How to select and close already open images on ImageJ macro
I try to build a very simple macro on Image J but cannot manage to close automatically the unwanted images and to treat the wanted images.
If you open a multichannel image and run Split Channels, ImageJ will open three new image windows: one for the red channel, one for the green channel, and one for the blue channel. Each of these windows will have a name ending with (red), (green), or (blue).
Here is the original macro :
run("Split Channels"); 
close();
selectImage("image.jpg (red)");
close();
selectImage("image.jpg (blue)");
close();

selectImage("image.jpg (green)");
setAutoThreshold("Default dark no-reset");
run("Threshold...");
setThreshold(0, 38);
setOption("BlackBackground", true);
run("Convert to Mask");

waitForUser("Please crop the image manually and click 'OK' to continue.");

run("Analyze Particles...", "display clear summarize add");


Then I tried to select and close specifically red and blue images, with this :
openWindows = getList("window.titles");

for (i = 0; i < openWindows.length; i++) {
    if (indexOf(openWindows[i], "(red)") != -1) {
        selectWindow(openWindows[i]);
        close();
    } else if (indexOf(openWindows[i], "(blue)") != -1) {
        selectWindow(openWindows[i]);
        close();
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < openWindows.length; i++) {
    if (indexOf(openWindows[i], "(green)") != -1) {
        selectWindow(openWindows[i]);
        break; 
    }
}


To finally apply the threshold to the (green) image and continue to modify it.
But this code doesn't work and apply threshold to the blue channel, which is the first one to open.
COuld you help me improve this ? :))

If you get split colour channel images that end with the colour name, then you originally deal with RGB-images not with multi-channel images. The latter lead to colour channel images that start with C1- and continue as C2-, C3-, etc. Please make sure about the original file format!

Below please find an ImageJ-demo macro that shows how to keep only one colour channel of an RGB-image:
//imagej-macro "keep1channel" (Herbie G., 26. Sept. 2024)
requires("1.54j");
close("*");
run("Clown"); // load the sample image
if (bitDepth()!=24) exit("RGB-image required!");
a=newArray("red","green","blue");
Dialog.create("Keep only one RGB-channel");
   Dialog.addChoice("Keep",a,a[1]);
Dialog.show();
clr=Dialog.getChoice();
setBatchMode(true);
run("Split Channels");
a=getList("image.titles");
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
   selectImage(a[i]);
   if (!a[i].contains(clr))
      close();
   else
      run(replace(clr,substring(clr,0,1),toUpperCase(substring(clr,0,1))));
}
//
// next: do what you want with the selected channel image
//
setBatchMode(false);
exit();
//imagej-macro "keep1channel" (Herbie G., 26. Sept. 2024)

(You need an open internet connection to load the sample image.)
